# Не работает веб-сервер NGINX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

Здравствуйте, не могу понять в чем дело, есть готовое приложение на Angular+RailsAPI сделал пока что деплой NGINX с Rails (клиентскую часть Angular позже подключу) настроил nginx.conf проверил конфигурацию, посмотрел вроде все как работает. Дальше делаю рестарт сервера в терминале написано что все запущено, затем захожу в браузер и ввожу имя сервера и нечего не происходит выводит только ошибку "The requested URL could not be retrieved". Подскажите пожалуйста что не так (если нужно скинуть конфиг или что-то еще напишите).

**config/nginx.conf:**

```
upstream puma {
  server unix:///home/solovievga/phonebook-api/tmp/sockets/puma.sock;
}


server {
  listen 80;

  root /home/solovievga/phonebook-api/current/public;
  access_log /home/solovievga/phonebook-api/shared/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /home/solovievga/phonebook-api/shared/log/nginx.error.log info;

 # location ^~ /assets/ {
   # gzip_static on;
   # expires max;
   # add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

# если нужен ActionCable
 # location /cable {
     # proxy_pass http://puma/cable;
     # proxy_http_version 1.1;
     # proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     # proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
 # }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://puma;
  }

  #error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 50M;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:**

```
user nobody;
worker_processes 2;

events {
worker_connections 4096;
# multi_accept on;
}

http {

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
# server_tokens off;

# server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
# server_name_in_redirect off;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;


log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user[$time_local] "$request"'
'$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
'"$http_user_agent" "http_x_forwarded_for"'

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;


gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

# gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;
# gzip_comp_level 6;
# gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;


include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enables/*.conf;
}
```

**config/deploy/production.rb:**

```
role :app, %w{10.12.4.245}

role :web, %w{10.12.4.245}

role :db, %w{10.12.4.245}

server '10.12.4.245', user: 'solovievga', roles: %w{web app db}

set :rails_env, 'production'

set :rvm_type, :user

set :rvm_ruby_version, 'ruby-2.4.2'
```

**deploy.rb:**

```
lock "~> 3.10.0"

set :application, -> {'phonebook-api'}
set :repo_url, 'git@bitbucket.org:solovievga/phonebookapi.git'

set :user, 'solovievga'
set :rvm_ruby_version, 'ruby-2.4.2'
set :tmp_dir, "/home/solovievga/phonebook-api/tmp"
ask :branch, proc { `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp }

set :puma_threads,    [4, 6]
set :puma_workers,    2

set :pty, true
set :use_sudo, false
set :stage, -> {:production} # по умолчанию production
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :deploy_to, -> {"/home/#{fetch(:user)}/#{fetch(:application)}"}
set :puma_bind, -> {"unix:///home/solovievga/phonebook-api/tmp/sockets/puma.sock;"}
set :puma_state, -> {"/home/solovievga/phonebook-api/tmp/pids/puma.state"}
set :puma_pid, -> {"/home/solovievga/phonebook-api/tmp/pids/puma.pid"}
set :puma_access_log, -> {"#{release_path}/log/puma.error.log"}
set :puma_error_log, ->  {"#{release_path}/log/puma.access.log"}
set :ssh_options,  { forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) }
set :puma_preload_app, true
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, true  # Change to false when not using ActiveRecord
set :nginx_use_ssl, false


set :log_level,     :debug
set :keep_releases, 3

## Linked Files & Directories (Default None):
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml config/secrets.yml}
set :linked_dirs,  %w{log tmp public/uploads}
```

Comment: Скинуть конфиг лишним не будет

Comment: @Darth, хорошо, уже скинул сразу вместе с деплоем

Comment: Опишите еще подробнее, как рестарт делаете? И что делали для авто-поднятия сервисов после рестарта?

Comment: @cheops, я все делал по этому гайду: http://fsdev.blog/2017/11/5-how-to-make-deploy-ror-with-puma-nginx рестарт делал так: sudo service nginx restart. Ключ залил на bitbucket.org. И что вы подразумеваете под "авто-поднятия сервисов"?

Comment: Ага, ясно, т.е. само Rails-приложение (puma) не рестартиться, перегрузке подвергается только nginx. А puma в процессах висит? ps aux | grep puma ?

Comment: @cheops, я сделал $ sudo service nginx restart   $ ps aux | grep puma
solovie+ 50131  0.0  0.0 112680   976 pts/1    R+   16:51   0:00 grep --color=auto puma
Но результат такой же http://s1.radikale.ru/uploads/2017/12/13/ce407a6bbdd41f3818fecc4cc7b54478-full.png

Comment: Похоже, что puma не запущена и nginx поэтому не может до нее достучаться

Comment: Загляни в лог нгинкса да глянь в чем дело